# Basic behavior of ammonia in aqueous medium

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, aqueous-solution, ions

Thanks to the reversible reaction

$$\ce{NH3 + H2O <=> NH4+ + OH-},\tag{R1}$$

we know that ammonia acts as a weak base. However, I was wondering why it ends up forming ammonium $\ce{NH4+}$ and not azanide $\ce{NH2-}$ according to

$$\ce{NH3 + H2O <=> NH2- + H3O+}.\tag{R2}$$

Comment: Search the pKa of NH3/NH2-

Comment: @Waylander I mean at a molecular level. I know that its pKa explains this.

Comment: @daviddavid [That's what you'd expect in *liquid* ammonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonia#Self-dissociation): $$\ce{2 NH3 ⇌ NH4+ + NH2-}$$

Comment: And why can't you expect this in an ammonia solution?

Comment: @andselisk Why does ammonia end up being NH4 instead of NH2?

Comment: It might, but the equilibrium lies far to the left. Hence, ammonia is not a very effective acid in water.

Comment: NH3 much easier accepts a proton than releases one.

Comment: As NH2 is a strong base and NH4 is a weak acid we then have a weak base (NH3)?

Comment: There are 2 separate conjugated pairs acid/base. What mystery is in that ? It is similar situation as H2PO4- Vs HPO4^2- Vs PO4^3-. . 2 pairs of acid/base as well.

Comment: The conjugate acid of a strong base (and NH2- is a *strong* base) is *very* weak. And a very weak acid like NH3 doesn't protonate water.

Comment: @Karl NH3 is a weak base ...

Comment: @daviddavid In your second equation above, it acts as an *acid*. That's what your question is about.

Answer (score 0):

All what Karl and Poutnik are saying is right. But the real question is : Why ? Why is $\ce{NH3}$ more reluctant to loose one proton than $\ce{H2O}$, at the atomic level ? Why is $\ce{NH2^-}$ such a strong base ?

Let's compare this behaviour in the series $\ce{N-O-F}$. Starting with $\ce{F}$, we can observe that $\ce{F}$ holds one $\ce{H}$, only one $\ce{H}$, and it does not hesitate to give its unique $\ce{H}$ atom (as a proton) to a great variety of bases. The next in line, the oxygen atom $\ce{O}$ can hold two $\ce{H}$ atoms. This is one more than what does $\ce{F}$. Well, $\ce{O}$ in $\ce{H2O}$ is also more reluctant to loose one $\ce{H}$, and accepts to give it (as a proton) only to strong bases. The third in line is the nitrogen atom $\ce{N}$ which can hold three $\ce{H}$ atoms. It's still more than what does Oxygen. But $\ce{N}$ in $\ce{NH3}$ is still more reluctant to loose one of its three $\ce{H}$ atoms as a proton $\ce{H+}$. It even prefers stealing one $\ce{H+}$ ion from the neighborhood rather than giving it. Apparently the more $\ce{H}$ atoms the central atom has, the more it wants to increase this number. It looks like the human society : the more money you've got, the more you want to increase your fortune.

Edit :
Of course it would be interesting to see if this tendency $\ce{F-O-N}$ can be extrapolated to the carbon atom. If my reasoning is correct, the Carbon atom in $\ce{CH4}$ should be extremely reluctant to loose one $\ce{H+}$ ion for producing $\ce{CH3^-}$. Indeed I am not sure that the ion $\ce{CH3^-}$ does exist, and has a measured $p\mathrm{K_a}$ value. It should be extremely high. On the other hand, $\ce{CH4}$ should be eager to get one more Hydrogen. However the electronic situation is not similar to $\ce{F, O}$ and $\ce{N}$. In $\ce{HF, H2O, NH3, F^-, OH^-, NH2^-, H3O+, NH4^+}$, the central atom has always the electronic state of Neon. It is known that $\ce{CH4}$ does produce $\ce{CH5^+}$ ion in high pressure mass spectrometry. But the electronic structure of the carbon atom in $\ce{CH5^+}$ is unknown, to my knowledge. So I am not sure whether the tendency, valid for $\ce{F-O-N}$, can be extrapolated to the Carbon atom.

Comment: @KarstenTheis Methane is CH4 ...

Comment: You've only said that it is more reluctant to lose it but you haven't actually said why.

Comment: @David. The only reason is the result of experiment.

Comment: @Maurice I don't think you get it. Results have to be reasoned theoretically and checked practically (with experiments). I am asking for the theoretical explanation.